# rewrite the value of html head > base > href

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, header, httpd.conf

I am trying to change the value of the **base href** tag in the header with apache httpd 4.2.23.

This is my header:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>hello</title>
   <base href="http://middleware.mylinux.com:8082/hello-app-0.0.7/">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="image/favicon.ico">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
```

I tired to use substitute module but i think that it works on body instead of header section of the html document.

The original documentation says:

> mod_substitute provides a mechanism to perform both regular expression
>   and fixed string substitutions on response bodies.

Could you please tell me what is the proper way to rewrite the header base content?

Thank you!

Comment: no, when it refers to bodies, there it refrs to "http" bodies, not html bodies. Help people help you by telling what you tried and didn't work. And if you specify from what you want to change that value to, you may even get a complete example of what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the meaning of "bodies" keyword in this context. So it seems that I can use "Substitute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines work fine:

```
<VirtualHost>
      # replace "middleware.mylinux.com:8082/hello-app-0.0.7" to "web.mylinux.com/hello"
      AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
      Substitute "s|middleware.mylinux.com:8082/hello-app-0.0.7|web.mylinux.com/hello|ni" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for the comment @ezra-s.